# functioning ( behavioural based ) of an antivirus

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware, virus-removal

I know how signatures are used to detect malware samples of already known malware and techniques to apply to use.

1.What are some of the different behavioral techniques used by antivirus/anti-malware ?

2. If would want to use some behavioral techniques then how to use? like in the signature base we could directly take a file and on the basis of that scan files/process/etc.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of heuristic techniques used by antivirus software. This is an incredibly broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are common ways malware works - currently quite a few are using powershell for example to call out download the payload and execute. This is normally trigger from say Word.exe calling cmd.exe has then called powershell.exe with arguments.

So detecting if a process for cmd.exe has been created by word is an indicator of **potential** malware activity and has a child process of powershell.exe.

Now there are quite a few common attacks that have indicators such as these listed by mitre:
https://attack.mitre.org/wiki/ATT%26CK_Matrix

Given known attack types you can detect this behaviour and respond. If you start grouping the different types of chained attacks you would expect you can determine if to a certain degree if something is malacious. 
A good example of a tool that monitors for malicious behaviour is [sysmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon)

Sysmon can be configured to only look for certain types of behavior and writes to the windows event log.

Obviously if a new attack category with new indicators this becomes a problem.
So now you also begin to determine what is normal behaviour on a system using some ai techniques so if something out of the normal occurs it can be flagged and other indicators looked at.